# Issues with converting HTML file to master page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Right now I have an HTML file and I'm trying to convert it to a master page. I'm using a VM on CloudShare.

So I create a new site collection and go into the site settings. Under “Look and Feel”, Design Manager isn’t there so I’ve found that if I go to “Site Collection Features” under “Site Collection Administration”, and activate “SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure” Design Manager will show up. So I go into design manager, but under Edit Master Pages none of the file or folder names will show up, and when I convert the html file the status column doesn’t show up either, so I can’t go to preview it or to the snippets gallery.

The only thing I can find online is to create a new site collection, which I’ve tried a few times. This happened on my old CloudShare VM, and creating a new site collection fixed it, but it’s not working for this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Also, CloudShare is being sooo slooow which isn't helping.

Comment: Figured it out - I made a new site collection and set it to a Publishing site template and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I made a new site collection and set it to a Publishing site template and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Personally when working with new master pages I have found that the best application to use is SharePoint Designer. You should be able to download it for free. Here are the instructions to configure SharePoint designer using it with CloudShare.

http://blog.cloudshare.com/tag/sharepoint-designer/